# Cache-Control Header Modified By PHP Session?

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

I'm outputting an image to the browser using a `Zend_Controller_Response` object.  It is my intention to apply caching to the image, however something is causing the Cache-Control header to be overwritten.

My code is as follows:

```
$this->getResponse()
    ->setHeader('Last-Modified', $modifiedTime, true)
    ->setHeader('ETag', md5($modifiedTime), true)
    ->setHeader('Expires', $expires, true)
    ->setHeader('Pragma', '', true)
    ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600')
    ->setHeader('Content-Type', $mimeType, true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Length', $size, true)
    ->setBody($data);
```

The output (as viewed in Firebug) is:

**Response Headers**

> Date
>
> Wed, 25 Mar 2009 10:34:40 GMT
>
> Server
>
> Apache/2.2.3 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8c
>
> Expires
>
> Thu, 26 Mar 2009 10:34:41 GMT
>
> Cache-Control
>
> no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=3600
>
> Last-Modified
>
> 1234872514
>
> Etag
>
> d3ef646c640b689b0101f3e03e08a524
>
> Content-Length
>
> 1452
>
> X-UA-Compatible
>
> IE=EmulateIE7
>
> X-Robots-Tag
>
> noindex
>
> Keep-Alive
>
> timeout=15, max=100
>
> Connection
>
> Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type
>
> image/jpeg

**Request Headers**

> Host
>
> khall.####.###.######.com
>
> User-Agent
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009030422 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/3.0
> .7
>
> Accept
>
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language
>
> en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding
>
> gzip,deflate
>
> Accept-Charset
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
> Keep-Alive
>
> 300
>
> Connection
>
> keep-alive
>
> Referer
>
> http://khall.####.###.######.com/
>
> Cookie
>
> PHPSESSID=abf5056e1289d3010448107632a1c1bd

As you can see, the cache control is modified to include:

> no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

My suspicion is towards the session cookie being sent in the request.  Does anybody know a way to send the header that I require, yet still keep the session in the request?  My application is run through a bootstrap, and sessions are handled using Zend_Session.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Zend_Controller documentation, section [10.9. The Response Object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.response.html)

> setHeader($name, $value, $replace =
>   false) is used to set an individual
>   header. By default, it does not
>   replace existing headers of the same
>   name in the object; however, setting
>   $replace to true will force it to do
>   so.

The problem you are having is your max-age=3600 is being appended to the cache-control header, as opposed to replacing it. Try setting the **$replace** parameter to **true**.

Comment: GAH!  I should smack myself in the face.  I thought I was passing that parameter!  You are quite right though, that is the answer.

Comment: Hehe, I do it all the time! Proof? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657600/how-do-i-correctly-create-a-zend-feed

Answer (score 28):

You're right by assuming that this behaviour is connected to the session mechanism in PHP.  There is a configuration setting `session.cache_limiter` that controls the caching HTTP headers that will be sent with the response. The default setting here is `nocache` which sends

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
Pragma: no-cache
```

You overwrite all of these headers within your controller besides the `Cache-Control`-header (you only append your `max-age=3600` setting here).

Possible solutions are:

1. changing the PHP configuration ([`session.cache_limiter`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter)) to e.g. `none` - but this could introduce problems to other PHP applications
2. set the `session.cache_limiter` on each request using [`session_cache_limiter()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php)
3. overwrite the full `Cache-Control`-header in your controller with the designated string

The possible values for `session.cache_limiter` and `session_cache_limiter()` are:

**none**: no header will be sent

**nocache**:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

**private**:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800
```

**private_no_expire**:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800
```

**public**:

```
Expires: pageload + 3 hours
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The problem was my hasty coding, as karim79 pointed out: the problem is more Zend Framework based.  Thanks for the insight, though.

Comment: Nice, this solved my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937581/php-remove-http-header