# PHP Session Adding Headers Pragma: no-cache

Tags: php, session, http-headers

**Hi People, i have problem with http headers request, when i test header i get this response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2016 14:24:31 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.27
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
    check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2d17992cfbd621c51eca940df478b89a; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Security-Policy: allow 'self';
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: it-it
```

### **This part ist come out only if i have session_start() on page**

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
    check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

---

### On clean pages .php or .html pages i get this respond

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2016 14:34:27 GMT
    Server: Apache
    Last-Modified: Sat, 29 Oct 2016 13:15:00 GMT
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Length: 314
    Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    Cache-Control: max-age=604800, must-revalidate
    Expires: Sat, 29 Oct 2016 14:34:27 GMT
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    X-Content-Security-Policy: allow 'self';
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Language: it-it
```

---

**I try search evrywhere but no idea im bloked
Sombody have idea why session_start(); add**

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
    check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

**in http headers????????**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache-Control Header Modified By PHP Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681115/cache-control-header-modified-by-php-session)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

```
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire:');
session_start();
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks for sharing!